# Can't i add android-17,android-18 etc platforms in android studio?

Tags: android, android-sdk-tools

I downloaded android studio version v0.8.0 and it has platform android-20..I want to add android-17,android-18,android-19 platforms in it.How can i do it??Can i use androids other platforms in android studio.Because in their sdk platforms are present only for android-20..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can surely use `API-17,18,19` or any other API's.Go to `Tools->Android->SDK Manager` and install the required version and after installing restart studio.And in your manifest file or your application's build.gradle file use the required version.And also update your Android Studio to 0.8.9 which is stable version

Comment: https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html here only 0.8.6 version is released

Comment: 0.8.6 is the stable version after installing it update it to 0.8.9 from the dev channel which is actually the latest build